# standalone parent pom deployment issue

Tags: apache, maven, archiva, parent-pom

I'm having a simple parent pom for a centralized definition of the company name and the connection to the artifact repository

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>pom-company</artifactId>
    <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <organization>
        <name>My company name</name>
    </organization>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:http://gitlab/projects/pom-company.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@gitlab/projects/pom-company.git</developerConnection>
        <url>http://gitlab/projects/pom-company</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>archiva.internal</id>
            <name>Internal Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://archiva/repository/internal</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

It also contains a proven valid `<scm>` connection. Now I `release:prepare` && `release:perform` but the artifact (version 1.3 in this case) will not be deployed as expected to the artifact repository by maven. Surprisingly the Snapshot version has been deployed. The corresponding profile in my `settings.xml` tells only to enable the upload of releases, not snapshots. This configuration worked so far for every other project.

Another strange fact is that the pom.xml remains in changed but not checked in status for git after the process. The only thing that is marked as changed is this one in the `pom.xml`:

```
<version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

**I have no idea what the reason could be and hope that someone has an idea.**

---

### Update

- I have corrected the project version in the upper `pom.xml` from 1.4-SNAPSHOT to 1.3-SNAPSHOT
- additional info: the project consists of nothing else but only the `pom.xml`
- I use the maven version 3.3.1
- Here is the output of `release:prepare` as requested in a comment:

  ```
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Building pom-company 1.3-SNAPSHOT
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  --- maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) @ pom-company ---
  Verifying that there are no local modifications...
    ignoring changes on: **/pom.xml.backup, **/release.properties, **/pom.xml.branch, **/pom.xml.next, **/pom.xml.releaseBackup, **/pom.xml.tag
  Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company && git status
  Working directory: /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company
  Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
  What is the release version for "pom-company"? (de.company:pom-company) 1.3: : 
  What is SCM release tag or label for "pom-company"? (de.company:pom-company) pom-company-1.3: : 
  What is the new development version for "pom-company"? (de.company:pom-company) 1.4-SNAPSHOT: : 
  Transforming 'pom-company'...
  Not generating release POMs
  Executing goals 'clean verify'...
  Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
  [INFO] Scanning for projects...
  [INFO]                                                                         
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Building pom-company 1.3
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ pom-company ---
  [INFO] Deleting /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company/target
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time: 0.276 s
  [INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-21T07:56:41+02:00
  [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/239M
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Checking in modified POMs...
  Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company && git add -- pom.xml
  Working directory: /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company
  Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company && git status
  Working directory: /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company
  Tagging release with the label pom-company-1.3...
  Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company && git tag -F /tmp/maven-scm-215434904.commit pom-company-1.3
  Working directory: /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company
  Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company && git push git@gitlab:projects/pom-company.git pom-company-1.3
  Working directory: /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company
  Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company && git ls-files
  Working directory: /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company
  Transforming 'pom-company'...
  Not removing release POMs
  Checking in modified POMs...
  Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company && git add -- pom.xml
  Working directory: /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company
  Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company && git status
  Working directory: /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company
  Release preparation complete.
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  BUILD SUCCESS
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Total time: 43.212 s
  Finished at: 2015-05-21T07:56:48+02:00
  Final Memory: 11M/239M
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ```
- and the output of `release:perform`:

  ```
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Building pom-company 1.4-SNAPSHOT
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  --- maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:perform (default-cli) @ pom-company ---
  Checking out the project to perform the release ...
  Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company/target && git clone --branch pom-company-1.3 git@gitlab:projects/pom-company.git /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company/target/checkout
  Working directory: /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company/target
  Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /tmp && git ls-remote git@gitlab:projects/pom-company.git
  Working directory: /tmp
  Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company/target/checkout && git fetch git@gitlab:projects/pom-company.git
  Working directory: /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company/target/checkout
  Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company/target/checkout && git checkout pom-company-1.3
  Working directory: /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company/target/checkout
  Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company/target/checkout && git ls-files
  Working directory: /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company/target/checkout
  Invoking perform goals in directory /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company/target/checkout
  Executing goals 'deploy'...
  Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
  [INFO] Scanning for projects...
  [WARNING] 
  [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for de.lotto.nds:pom-company:pom:1.3-SNAPSHOT
  [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing.
  [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing.
  [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin is missing.
  [WARNING] 
  [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
  [WARNING] 
  [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
  [WARNING] 
  [INFO]                                                                         
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Building pom-company 1.3-SNAPSHOT
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Downloading: http://archiva/repository/internal/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-source-plugin/maven-metadata.xml

  Downloaded: http://archiva/repository/internal/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-source-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (747 B at 0.6 KB/sec)
  Downloading: http://archiva/repository/internal/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/maven-metadata.xml

  Downloaded: http://archiva/repository/internal/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (911 B at 32.9 KB/sec)
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar (attach-sources) > generate-sources @ pom-company >>>
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar (attach-sources) < generate-sources @ pom-company <<<
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar (attach-sources) @ pom-company ---
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:jar (attach-javadocs) @ pom-company ---
  [INFO] Not executing Javadoc as the project is not a Java classpath-capable package
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ pom-company ---
  [INFO] Installing /home/thomas/workspace/maven/pom-company/target/checkout/pom.xml to /home/thomas/.m2/repository/de/company/pom-company/1.3-SNAPSHOT/pom-company-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ pom-company ---
  Downloading: http://archiva/repository/internal/de/company/pom-company/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

  Downloaded: http://archiva/repository/internal/de/company/pom-company/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (354 B at 0.1 KB/sec)
  Uploading: http://archiva/repository/internal/de/company/pom-company/1.3-SNAPSHOT/pom-company-1.3-20150521.060109-2.pom

  Uploaded: http://archiva/repository/internal/de/company/pom-company/1.3-SNAPSHOT/pom-company-1.3-20150521.060109-2.pom (2 KB at 26.3 KB/sec)
  Downloading: http://archiva/repository/internal/de/company/pom-company/maven-metadata.xml

  Downloaded: http://archiva/repository/internal/de/company/pom-company/maven-metadata.xml (426 B at 34.7 KB/sec)
  Uploading: http://archiva/repository/internal/de/company/pom-company/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

  Uploaded: http://archiva/repository/internal/de/company/pom-company/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (592 B at 36.1 KB/sec)
  Uploading: http://archiva/repository/internal/de/company/pom-company/maven-metadata.xml

  Uploaded: http://archiva/repository/internal/de/company/pom-company/maven-metadata.xml (425 B at 27.7 KB/sec)
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time: 6.222 s
  [INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-21T08:01:09+02:00
  [INFO] Final Memory: 16M/239M
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Cleaning up after release...
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  BUILD SUCCESS
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Total time: 10.550 s
  Finished at: 2015-05-21T08:01:10+02:00
  Final Memory: 11M/239M
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ```

Comment: Without the full pom impossible to say what's the problem is...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have added the full content in the question.

Comment: Which Maven Version? Which Version of maven-release-plugin do you use? Can you show a log file which running the release process? Are you running from command line or on a CI solution or from within an IDE?

Comment: Did you try the release plugin with another version? I suggest this to discard things. The latest is the 2.5.2. You could add it in your pom.xml and see what happens

Comment: @IkerAguayo Bravo! That works. Just post this as an answer and I'll reward. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the release plugin with another version? The latest is the 2.5.2. You could add it in your pom.xml and see what happens

```
 <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
      </plugin>
      [...]
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
```